# How can I make Puppet run a command once?

Tags: puppet

Sometimes I want to run a command one time on all servers, e.g.

```
service ntpd stop
ntpdate ntp3.domain.local
service ntpd start
```

How can I make Puppet run this command once on all servers? I want to avoid this command being run every 30 minutes.

And if Puppet isn't the right tool for this, then what is?

Comment: MCollective is probably what you want to look at.

Comment: Also, if you use `ntpdate -u` you don't have to stop ntpd.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably an at job:
[Examples for at jobs](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the 'unless' parameter of exec.

Official documentation here: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/exec.html

For example, you can add one last command to touch a file, and use 'cat filename' in your 'unless' parameter.  If the file exists, the exec won't run :)

Comment: Same idea with 'onlyif', btw ;)